# Understanding a localhost Image loading error in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, image, error-handling

How can I find the error of the following error report?

```
GET http://localhost:8080/img/%7B%7BCurrentPage.img%7D%7D 404 (Not Found) angular.js:2763

r.html angular.js:2763
S.(anonymous function) angular.js:2810
(anonymous function) angular-ui-router.min.js:7
N angular.js:6711
g angular.js:6105
(anonymous function) angular.js:6001
j angular-ui-router.min.js:7
(anonymous function) angular-ui-router.min.js:7
k.$broadcast angular.js:12981
u.transition.L.then.u.transition.u.transition angular-ui-router.min.js:7
F angular.js:11573
(anonymous function) angular.js:11659
k.$eval angular.js:12702
k.$digest angular.js:12514
k.$apply angular.js:12806
h angular.js:8379
u angular.js:8593
z.onreadystatechange angular.js:8532
```

The `%7B%7BCurrentPage.img%7D%7D` is a `{{CurrentPage.img}}`, which returns the image name and is working, why is this error in my console?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

To break your error down:

```
%7B%7BCurrentPage.img%7D%7D
```

Your image source is url encoded, where:

```
%7B%7B is {{
```

and

```
%7D%7D is }}
```

Once the page loads your browser tries to get the image specified by

```
<img src="{{CurrentPage.img}}">
```

but angular hasn't had a chance yet to evaluate the expression. The broswer then tries get the image specified by the raw text `"{{CurrentPage.img}}"` and encodes it so you get:

```
<img src="%7B%7BCurrentPage.img%7D%7D">
```

And are unable to get an image specified by that url:

```
http://localhost:8080/%7B%7BCurrentPage.img%7D%7D
```

Because nothing exists there. To get around this use [ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc):

```
<img ng-src="{{CurrentPage.img}}">
```

That prevents the browser from loading the image before its properly evaluated by angular.

Comment: That solve my problem but i guess you knew the answer from first line of my error report. How the rest lines of error report can help me in error find?

Comment: @GoncharDenys Do you still have this problem when you use `ngSrc`?

Comment: the rest of the lines specify where the stack trace thrown by the error. It lets you track-down the path your application took to get there so you can begin to debug the issue. Since this issue in in the core of angular, its not particularly helpful, but if an error was thrown by a method in one of your controllers, the stack trace would easily lead you there.

Comment: @GoncharDenys do you mean do I use ng-src? if so then yes.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the {{ and }} encodings. Your solutions works great - nice and easy.

Answer (score 5):

This error happens when you use `img` with `src` attribute instead of [`ngSrc`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc). You should use this notation:

```
<img ng-src="CurrentPage.img" alt="" />
```

The problem is that when you use `src="{{CurrentPage.img}}"` syntax, browser starts downloading a resource making an HTTP request before Angular resolves binding and replace `{{CurrentPage.img}}` with actual image path:

```
http://localhost:8080/img/%7B%7BCurrentPage.img%7D%7D
```

(urlencoded `{{CurrentPage.img}}`). Obviously it will result in a 404 error.

On the other hand, `ng-src` attribute doesn't mean anything to browser so it won't do anything, until Angular is ready and [ngSrc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) directive creates `src` attribute with proper URL.